# MySql - Handle table size and performance

Tags: mysql, database, query-performance

We are having a Analytics product. For each of our customer we give one JavaScript code, they put that in their web sites. If a user visit our customer site the java script code hit our server so that we store this page visit on behalf of this customer. Each customer contains unique domain name.

we are storing this page visits in MySql table.

Following is the table schema.

```
CREATE TABLE `page_visits` (
  `domain` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `guid` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sid` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` varchar(2500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_new` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ref` varchar(2500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_agent` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `stats_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `region` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city_lat_long` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `sid_index` (`sid`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `domain_index` (`domain`),
  KEY `email_index` (`email`),
  KEY `stats_time_index` (`stats_time`),
  KEY `domain_statstime` (`domain`,`stats_time`),
  KEY `domain_email` (`domain`,`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

We don't have primary key for this table.

MySql server details

It is Google cloud MySql (version is 5.6) and storage capacity is 10TB.

As of now we are having 350 million rows in our table and table size is 300 GB. We are storing all of our customer details in the same table even though there is no relation between one customer to another.

**Problem 1**: For few of our customers having huge number of rows in table, so performance of queries against these customers are very slow.

Example Query 1:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT sid) AS count,count(sid) AS total FROM page_views WHERE domain = 'aaa' AND stats_time BETWEEN CONVERT_TZ('2015-02-05 00:00:00','+05:30','+00:00') AND CONVERT_TZ('2016-01-01 23:59:59','+05:30','+00:00');
+---------+---------+
| count   | total   |
+---------+---------+
| 1056546 | 2713729 |
+---------+---------+
1 row in set (13 min 19.71 sec)
```

I will update more queries here. We need results in below 5-10 seconds, will it be possible?

**Problem 2**: The table size is rapidly increasing, we might hit table size 5 TB by this year end so we want to shard our table. We want to keep all records related to one customer in one machine. What are the best practises for this sharding.

We are thinking following approaches for above issues, please suggest us best practices to overcome these issues.

Create separate table for each customer

1) What are the advantages and disadvantages if we create separate table for each customer. As of now we are having 30k customers we might hit 100k by this year end that means 100k tables in DB. We access all tables simultaneously for Read and Write.

2) We will go with same table and will create partitions based on date range

**UPDATE** : Is a "customer" determined by the domain? **Answer is Yes**

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, a critique if the **excessively large datatypes**:

```
  `domain` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,  -- normalize to MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED (3 bytes)
  `guid` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,  -- what is this for?
  `sid` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,  -- varchar?
  `url` varchar(2500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,  -- too big for IPv4, too small for IPv6; see below
  `is_new` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,  -- flag?  Consider `TINYINT` or `ENUM`
  `ref` varchar(2500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_agent` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  -- normalize! (add new rows as new agents are created)
  `stats_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,  -- use standard 2-letter code (see below)
  `region` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,  -- see below
  `city` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,  -- see below
  `city_lat_long` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,  -- unusable in current format; toss?
  `email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
```

For IP addresses, use `inet6_aton()`, then store in `BINARY(16)`.

For `country`, use `CHAR(2) CHARACTER SET ascii` -- only 2 bytes.

country + region + city + (maybe) latlng -- normalize this to a "location".

All these changes may cut the disk footprint in half.  Smaller --> more cacheable --> less I/O --> faster.

**Other issues**...

To greatly speed up your `sid` counter, change

```
KEY `domain_statstime` (`domain`,`stats_time`),
```

to

```
KEY dss (domain_id,`stats_time`, sid),
```

That will be a "covering index", hence won't have to bounce between the index and the data 2713729 times -- the bouncing is what cost 13 minutes.  (`domain_id` is discussed below.)

This is redundant with the above index, `DROP` it:
  KEY `domain_index` (`domain`)

Is a "customer" determined by the `domain`?

Every InnoDB table must have a `PRIMARY KEY`.  There are 3 ways to get a PK; you picked the 'worst' one -- a hidden 6-byte integer fabricated by the engine.  I assume there is no 'natural' PK available from some combination of columns?  Then, an explicit `BIGINT UNSIGNED` is called for.  (Yes that would be 8 bytes, but various forms of maintenance need an *explicit* PK.)

If *most* queries include `WHERE domain = '...'`, then I recommend the following.  (And this will greatly improve all such queries.)

```
id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
domain_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,   -- normalized to `Domains`
PRIMARY KEY(domain_id, id),  -- clustering on customer gives you the speedup
INDEX(id)  -- this keeps AUTO_INCREMENT happy
```

Recommend you look into `pt-online-schema-change` for making all these changes.  However, I don't know if it can work without an explicit `PRIMARY KEY`.

"Separate table for each customer"?  *No*.  This is a common question; the resounding answer is No.  I won't repeat all the reasons for not having 100K tables.

**Sharding**

"Sharding" is splitting the data across multiple *machines*.

To do sharding, you need to have code somewhere that looks at `domain` and decides which server will handle the query, then hands it off.  Sharding is advisable when you have *write scaling* problems.  You did not mention such, so it is unclear whether sharding is advisable.

When sharding on something like `domain` (or `domain_id`), you could use (1) a hash to pick the server, (2) a dictionary lookup (of 100K rows), or (3) a hybrid.

I like the hybrid -- hash to, say, 1024 values, then look up into a 1024-row table to see which machine has the data.  Since adding a new shard and migrating a user to a different shard are major undertakings, I feel that the hybrid is a reasonable compromise.  The lookup table needs to be distributed to all clients that redirect actions to shards.

If your 'writing' is running out of steam, see [*high speed ingestion*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table) for possible ways to speed that up.

**PARTITIONing**

`PARTITIONing` is splitting the data across multiple "sub-tables".

There are only a [*limited number of use cases*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint) where partitioning buys you any performance.  You not indicated that any apply to your use case.  Read that blog and see if you think that partitioning might be useful.

You mentioned "partition by date range".  Will most of the queries include a date range?  If so, such partitioning *may* be advisable.  (See the link above for best practices.)  Some other options come to mind:

Plan A: `PRIMARY KEY(domain_id, stats_time, id)` But that is bulky and requires even more overhead on each secondary index.  (Each secondary index silently includes all the columns of the PK.)

Plan B: Have stats_time include microseconds, then tweak the values to avoid having dups.  Then use `stats_time` instead of `id`.  But this requires some added complexity, especially if there are multiple clients inserting data.  (I can elaborate if needed.)

Plan C: Have a table that maps stats_time values to ids.  Look up the id range before doing the real query, then use both `WHERE id BETWEEN ... AND stats_time ...`.  (Again, messy code.)

**Summary tables**

Are many of the queries of the form of counting things over date ranges?  Suggest having Summary Tables based perhaps on per-hour.  [*More discussion*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables).

`COUNT(DISTINCT sid)` is especially difficult to fold into summary tables.  For example, the unique counts for each hour cannot be added together to get the unique count for the day.  But I have a [*technique*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uniques) for that, too.

Comment: @James Thank you for the detailed explanation, could you share any links of explanation why 100k tables is not a good decision.

Comment: The 100K tables is a common question on this forum.  Here are some of the arguments against it:  OS overhead and slowdown; complexity in your code; very little advantage.  There would probably be lots of tiny tables and a few huge tables -- each extreme has its own inefficiencies.

Comment: @cloudpre - Thanks for the comment.  It's the type of stuff I love talking about.

Comment: @RickJames I will do schema corrections and optimize queries with proper indexes as per your suggestions. Just assume that even after all these changes suppose if we have huge index file that can't fit into memory in that case do we need shard our table?? or just range partition does the work ??. We have 10 storage capacity in instance.

Comment: Spinning drives?  Or SSDs?  What do you mean by "10 storage capacity"?

Comment: A common way to deal with `COUNT(...)` queries in huge databases is not to do them, at least not live.  Seriously -- won't the customer be satisfied with `over 1050000` or `about 1060000` instead of `exactly 1056546`?  There are multiple techniques to achieve that, and do it "instantly".  (I can discuss further; suggest starting a separate thread for that niche topic.)

Comment: (Back to your recent comment.)  Yes, even with `dss` and SSDs, the `SELECT` you posed might take 20 seconds in a cold cache.  Partitioning won't help; Sharding would help only if each shard has enough RAM to hold that and other indexes for its subset of the data.  Then, it could still take a few seconds.  A "few seconds" can be painful in a UI, so we are back to "not doing slow queries".

Comment: @RickJames Sorry for typo mistake. We have 10 TB storage capacity in the instance.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do this if i were you. First thing that come to mind would be, on receive a pageview message, i send the message to a queue so that a worker can pickup and insert to database later (in bulk maybe); also i increase the counter of `siteid:date` in redis (for example). Doing `count` in sql is just a bad idea for this scenario.

Comment: @Tran hey thank for your answer, do you anyway to do it on MySql

Comment: @Rams you want to do it anyway in sql?

Comment: @Tran we want to do it on any solution which available on cloud like Google cloud sql.

Comment: @Rams well rabbitmq and redis are available on google cloud.

Comment: @Tran ok I will look into this. Any suggestion on sql ??

Comment: @Rams you can use sql trigger on insert to update another table (count stat) the count you want. Anyway, the idea is not doing the count again and again but keep it in a separate place.